# When is $\tan(a+b)$ undefined?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

For what values of $a$ and $b$ is $\tan(a+b)$ undefined? What is the relationship between $a$ and $b$ when it is undefined?

What about for $\tan(a-b)$?

Comment: First answer: when is $\tan x$ undefined?

Comment: tan(x) is undefined when x= pi/2 +kpi

Comment: So, $\tan (\underbrace{a+b}_{=x})$ is undefined when ...

Comment: when a+b= pi/2+ kpi

Comment: @David Mitra that's some beautiful latex syntax

Answer (score 1):

Since $\tan \alpha$ is undefined whenever $\alpha = \frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi$ where $k$ ranges through the integers. Then it follows by setting $\alpha = a \pm b$ that $$\tan (a \pm b) \text{ is undefined when } \\ \\ \bbox[15px, border:blue solid 1px]{a\pm b = \frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi}$$

Where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

**Edit:** I suppose that the relationship between $a$ and $b$ would be that $\tan (a \pm b)$ is undefined when $$a = \frac{\pi}{2} \mp b + k\pi $$

Answer (score 0):

Always defined except when there is jump in sign of $\infty $  when $ a \pm b$  becomes odd multiples of $\pi/2.$

Answer (score 0):

In degrees:

$\tan(90)$ is undefined.

Therefore is $a+b=90$ or $a-b=90$ create undefined solutions for whatever $a$ and $b$ that fit this equation.

The tan of any odd multiple of $90$ such as $90, 270, 450,$ etc. is also undefined.

Comment: What about 270?

Comment: Any multiple of 90

Comment: Any odd* multiple. And why use degrees instead of radians?

Comment: @Omry That makes sense. I made the edit.